# Google Analytics with transactions - quanity mismatch?

Tags: google-analytics

We've been using Google Analytics reporting for some time now and we tend to focus on **GA > Conversions > Ecommerce > Transactions** (on left hand menu)

Columns:

- "Transaction" listing all orders with a transaction id e.g.
  SESS123_name
- "Revenue" listing €amount
- "Tax" listing €amount
- "Shipping" listing    €amount

and finally "Quantity" we show transaction numbers.

Yesterday (and now today), we have noticed that the Quantity column numbers are doubling to what we see when we view a transaction in detail

**e.g** Quantity = 4 then you click on the Transaction ID and it shows = 2

Answer (score 1):

How about older data? For example, the data around Dec 20 -- does it add up correctly if you look at the reports now? If they're all fine, then I'd chalk it down to a delay in processing data. Given that you don't send 'Quantity' in the transaction hit, there's no other reason I can think of to cause this difference.